# MySQL record modified by?

Tags: mysql, audit-logging

Does MySQL have a mechanism for auto-stamping the user account on a record when it is created or modified? I'm currently time-stamping creation and modification using MySQL's built-in functionality, but I would love to be able to easily track creation/modification by user as well, without having to add scripting to do so.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't even record the user who created a table, let alone individual rows in the table.

The closest thing is to create an audit log. There are plugins available for MySQL audit logs. See https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/02/15/mysql-mariadb-with-mariadb-auditing-plugin/ for a roundup of them.

Other than this, you would have to roll your own using triggers.